# My solution derives from several answers and comments, what to do?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answering

I asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122423/whats-the-simplest-class-for-a-child/) which, having read answers and comments, Should have been a very different question. Probably should have been flagged as opinion based =]

I've accepted the answer from [Carcer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28402/carcer) as they rightly questioned my throwing someone in the deep end of 5e, but in actual fact I'm first going with a suggestion from [Engineer Toast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/19484/engineer-toast) (in a comment on the question).

I was about to post an answer myself as such, in case other people stumble into the same problem - but my chosen solution (I'll try Heroes of Hesiod, and she can level-up to a lvl1 adult-5e-person once the basic mechanics are understood) isn't actually an answer to the question so my self-censor-mode kicked in.

Is this the correct way of dealing with the situation? I didn't want to change the title as it would invalidate good answers to the original question. But in hindsight it's not the question I should have asked.

Comment: This is exactly why we don't want people answering in comments. (Along with some other scenarios, like where someone's answer-comment is wrong but cannot be downvoted or edited.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like EngineerToast has now posted their own [answer based on their comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122693/28591) (after some encouragement and help from the community), so you might consider choosing that for your accepted answer if it meets your criteria and solves your issue. If not...

## Post your own answer

Answering your own question is not only acceptable, but it is actually encouraged! If none of the answers were what works best for you and you found another option, it is absolutely the best way to go to write up what worked for you in an answer.

In this case, the solution actually happens to be a frame challenge to your question, which is a perfectly acceptable way to answer a question. Basically, instead of answering the question directly, you challenge the premise of the question and offer a solution based off of that.

As a side note, this is one of the reasons we do not allow answering in the comments. Had EngineerToast put their answer as an actual answer they would now be getting the rep and the checkmark from writing a good answer and you would not be in a position where you were forced to write your own based off of it.

**Regardless, the checkmark should go to the answer that helped you solve your problem the best. And if you need to write your own answer to reflect that then that is the best way to go.** :)

Comment: I've now accepted the answer from EngineerToast. It doesn't directly answer the question, but is definitely the solution I'm looking for! Looks like the problem disappeared while I slept...

Comment: @ErosRising Glad it worked for you. Some members of the community got together and encouraged and helped EngineeerToast to convert his comment to an answer. And it looks like that worked out nicely for them. Thanks for following up on all of this!

Comment: I'm going to assume you drove that, so thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ErosRising actually I believe it was KorvinStarmast that helped him the most. :)

Comment: special thanks to @KorvinStarmast then!

Comment: @ErosRising Glad to be of help, hope the games go well. :)